# How to capture Network traffic using Java and get file type without using Proxy?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, xmlhttprequest, network-traffic

I need to capture network traffic using Java and get the File type.
eg: IF it is xmlHTTPrequest the File type is XHR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you actually want to do. But if you want a whole machine network sniffer (something like what whireshark is doing), libpcap or winpcap is probably what you're searching for. There is also a java library which handles the low level stuff: pcap4j